# Возможно ли вызвать функцию GetOpenFileNameA в Python без использования GUI-библиотек типа tkinter/PyQT?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

Мне нужно добавить в скрипт возможность выбора файла с помощью вызова диалогового окна Windows с выбором файлов, возможно ли добавить эту возможность не прибегая к использованию всяких графических библиотек типа tkinter/PyQT ?

Возможно ли реализовать это скажем на чистом win32api ?

Comment: Да, через win32 можно собрать любой интерфейс, но вопрос только зачем? В 10 раз сложнее, неудобнее и дольше..

Comment: @Amgarak я понимаю что это возможно, интересна была бы реализация

Comment: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/Demos/GetSaveFileName.py найти несложно...

Comment: rootkit.sys, т.е.  ваш скрипт предназначен только для  Windows ?